# Poster deletes question with valid answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions

I answered a question that as far as I can tell was never previously asked and the answer involved pointing the poster to a particular R package and I illustrated its use. He left a comment thanking me (but no checkmark or upvote , but who cares?). The poster had one rep point and may have been unaware that valid answers stay up (or this may have been a homework question?) Anyway, I [reposted a somewhat shorter version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864392/repost-how-to-represent-polynomials-with-numeric-vectors-in-r) and reposted my answer as well.

This seems sufficient for the current case, but what if it were more complicated question and answer. Is there are recovery mechanism for good answers attached to deleted questions, or are answers at the complete mercy of the OP? (I have searched Meta and not found an answer yet.)

Feature suggestion: Should low rep users be prevented from deleting posts with answers?

Comment: I don't think it needs the phrase 'Repost:' in the title, it is redundant information. Almost a meta-tag.

Comment: 10k link to deleted question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862801/trouble-mapping-vectors-arrays-into-polynomials-that-return-vector/16862902#16862902

Comment: Users are already prevented from deleting questions with *upvoted* answers.  The upvotes theoretically demonstrate that the community values the post.

Comment: Thank you @Oded: Excuse my cluelessness, but how did you find that link?

Comment: @DWin He is a dev. He can see things an ordinary user couldn't, in this case, your answer that is removed together with the question.

Comment: Yep, pretty much what @Antony said.

Comment: Or, y'now, [10K](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - You sure? DWin has +66k on SO, so should be able to see own deleted posts.

Comment: Isn't that deleted questions and answers are not shown on one's profile, except that 10k users can see them when they have the link?

Comment: You can see other people's deleted posts but not your own.  That's... kinda weird.

Comment: @RobertHarvey He can see it. He just didn't have the link.

Comment: Color me puzzled. I've been able to see my deleted posts in the past.

Comment: Are anyone but mods able to see anyone's deleted posts in their profiles?

Comment: I looked for the favorable comment in my Responses list. Nothing there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, no, we do not have profile links to our deleted content (nor anyone else's, obviously).

Comment: If you had any sort of reputation changes associated with the post, those changes would still show up in your *reputation history*, and if you have the required 10k rep, they'd still be linked to the actual post rather than plain-text. 10k users cannot see their deleted posts listed in their questions/answers lists. In this case, DWin's answer had a score of 0 so a reputation event was never created and thus he wouldn't have a link to the post.

Comment: Gotcha. . . . .

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I will need to look into the code, but I do think it is a mod only thing (seeing deleted posts in the account pages).

Comment: No need.  It seems pretty apparent that only diamonds have this capability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A moderator can undelete the question (and your answer with it), all you need to do is flag. Since the question has been deleted and you have no link to it, you can flag any of your own posts and *clearly* explain what's going on. Something like:

> A question about representing polynomials in R I answered was immediately deleted by the OP. Please consider undeleting it, I don't think my answer should go to waste. You'll find it by looking for my most recent deleted answer.

Of course this isn't necessary now that you've reposted it.

Comment: I am unsure _what_ to flag (if I were going to do that). There's no there there.

Comment: @DWin "you can flag any of your own posts" It doesn't really matter, pick one of your questions or answers and flag it. The important thing is for your flag to go through.